# Run jnlp applications with root permissions

Tags: 11.04, permissions, root

There is an application called KeyToolIUI, a java application that works with certificates, I want to give to it the root permission to be able to edit cacerts, when I am trying to run it from terminal as root, it gives me the following error:

> root@deveto: ~# -bash: keytool-iui.jnlp: Permission denied

Should I run it in other way? or it isn't possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

personally I would preferably not start java applications as root.

If you want to run it you should try sth like this:

```
javaws foo.jnlp
```

Details would be necessary to help you more.

greetings from Switzerland, Michael